# ADFv2 Date functions not accepting variables as arguments

Tags: azure-data-factory

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#date-functions) I am trying to use following date functions within pipeline JSON:-

```
adddays('2015-03-15T13:27:36Z', -int(variables('NumberOfDaysToSubtract')))
adddays('2015-03-15T13:27:36Z', -variables('NumberOfDaysToSubtract'))
adddays('2015-03-15T13:27:36Z', (-1*variables('NumberOfDaysToSubtract')))
```

None of the 3 approaches worked, the expressions are being treated as invalid. Only hardcoded value as shown below works:-

```
adddays('2015-03-15T13:27:36Z', -10)
```

I don't want to hardcode this value. It's smooth if I can somehow use the variable NumberOfDaysToSubtract that I have already defined for the pipeline with the default value as 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I figured is that setting the variable default value to **-10** and then using the following expression worked:-

```
adddays('2015-03-15T13:27:36Z', int(variables('NumberOfDaysToSubtract')))
```